# How to write Testcases for an API that accepts an object that includes IFormFile typed fields in .NET

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, iformfile

This is my controller code. Here it accepts `UpdateMediaDto` object that contains `IFormFile` data ( e.g. images and audios).

```
[HttpPut("words/{wordId}/medias/{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<WordMediaDto>> UpdateWordMedia(Guid wordId, Guid id, [FromForm] UpdateMediaDto mediaDto)
{
    WordMedia? media = await _unitOfWork.WordMediaRepository.GetByIdAsync(id);
    if (media == null) return NotFound();
    if (wordId != media.WordId) return BadRequest("No Word present for this media");
    var newMedia = _mediaFileMasterService.UpdateMedias(mediaDto);

    //............
}
```

And this is my testcase

```
[Fact]
public async Task PUT_Media_with_UpdateMediaDto_results_WordMediaDto_success()
{
    var ImagefileMock = new Mock<IFormFile>();
    var content = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("// byte[]....");
    var ImagefileName = "sampleImage.jpg";
    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    var writer = new StreamWriter(ms);
    writer.Write(content);
    writer.Flush();
    ms.Position = 0;
    ImagefileMock.Setup(_ => _.OpenReadStream()).Returns(ms);
    ImagefileMock.Setup(_ => _.FileName).Returns(ImagefileName);
    ImagefileMock.Setup(_ => _.Length).Returns(ms.Length);

    UpdateMediaDto mediaDto = new() {
        Id = Guid.Parse("f1659b04-85a3-4969-7d20-08da081a9616"),
        wordId=Guid.Parse("2caf24aa-4d37-4f64-aa91-4a605798c35b"),
        PrimaryImage=ImagefileMock.Object,
        SecondaryImage1 = ImagefileMock.Object };

    HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mediaDto), Encoding.UTF8);
    httpContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("multipart/form-data");
    //Act
    var response = await _httpClient.PutAsync("api/v1/admin/words/d9823bdd-0d11-42e5-a804-4d59d393d2bc/medias/f47136e3-754a-4f2b-b5cc-08da2d91a92e", httpContent);
    //Assert
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
  
}
```

But Here I can't serialize the object using `SerializeObject`. when I execute this test case I get an error like

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException : Self referencing loop detected for property 'Object' with type 'Castle.Proxies.IFormFileProxy'. Path 'PrimaryImage.Mock'.

How can I solve this problem... and is there any other ways to test API like this?

Answer (score 1):

The proxy created by MOQ is causing an issue with the serialization in this case.

Consider using an actual `FormFile` instance which is derived from `IFormFile`.

```
[Fact]
public async Task PUT_Media_with_UpdateMediaDto_results_WordMediaDto_success() {
    //Setup mock file using a memory stream
    string content = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("// byte[]....");
    string ImagefileName = "sampleImage.jpg";
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(ms);
    writer.Write(content);
    writer.Flush();
    ms.Position = 0;
    
    //create FormFile with desired data
    IFormFile ImagefileMock = new FormFile(ms, 0, ms.Length, "name_from_form", ImagefileName);
    
    UpdateMediaDto mediaDto = new() {
        Id = Guid.Parse("f1659b04-85a3-4969-7d20-08da081a9616"),
        wordId=Guid.Parse("2caf24aa-4d37-4f64-aa91-4a605798c35b"),
        PrimaryImage=ImagefileMock,
        SecondaryImage1 = ImagefileMock 
    };

    HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mediaDto), Encoding.UTF8);
    httpContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("multipart/form-data");
    //Act
    var response = await _httpClient.PutAsync("api/v1/admin/words/d9823bdd-0d11-42e5-a804-4d59d393d2bc/medias/f47136e3-754a-4f2b-b5cc-08da2d91a92e", httpContent);
    //Assert
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to use `MultipartFormDataContent` to build your form and add parts. To Stream objects use `StreamContent`.

```
var multiPartformData = new MultipartFormDataContent();
var streamContent = new StreamContent(ImagefileMock);
multiPartformData .Add(streamContent);
```